# How can I show video stream in Qt QML rectangle using deepstream pipeline?

Tags: qt, qml, pipeline, nvidia, rtsp

I have used the following deepstream pipeline in MediaPlayer object of QML. It works fine and it puts the video ouput in newly created window.

```
Rectangle
{
    MediaPlayer
    {
        id: cameraVideo
        autoPlay: true
        source: "gst-pipeline: uridecodebin3 
        uri=\"rtspt://192.168.1.118:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp\" ! queue ! 
        nvstreammux0.sink_0 nvstreammux name=nvstreammux0 batch-size=1 batched-push-timeout=40000 
        width=800 height=600 live-source=TRUE ! queue ! nvvideoconvert 
        ! queue ! nvinfer config-file-path=\"/opt/nvidia/deepstream
        /deepstream/samples/configs/deepstream-app/config_infer_primary_nano.txt\" ! 
        queue ! nvmultistreamtiler ! queue ! nvtracker tracker-width=240 tracker-height=200 
        ll-lib-file=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream/lib/libnvds_mot_iou.so  
        ll-config-file=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream/samples/configs/deepstream-app/iou_config.txt ! queue ! 
        nvdsosd process-mode=HW_MODE ! queue ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink"
    }
    VideoOutput
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: cameraVideo
    }
}
```

But I want to put video output in specified QML Rectangle which is parent of MediaPlayer object. It seems that I must use qtvideosink instead of nveglglessink. But which plugins should I use to transform the video stream for qtvideosink.
By the way the app is running on NVidia Jetson Nano.

Comment: You have a complex pipeline, it's difficult to help as many of us don't have that particular setup available! Simplify it and come back. For instance, are you able to define a simple pipeline to play a local video file in the specific region of the Rectangle? A more complex pipeline would be based on the same approach.

Comment: @karlphillip you are right. but i think that it is essential to declare all of the plugins which i used in pipeline. I can define the simple pipeline which gets the stream and show it in mediaplayer with no object detection. but i want to use object detection & traction plugins.